# Printing Word Length Histogram in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, histogram, kernighan-and-ritchie

Okay so I'm using Kernighan and Ritchie's "The C Programming Language" and I'm on exercise 1.13 and I can't seem to get this right. My program seems to not be printing much. The problem is as follows:

> Exercise 1-13. Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with
>   the bars horizontal; a vertical orientation is more challenging.

Besides the creation of variables, here's my pseudocode for reading the input and storing what I want to store in the array.

1. Create an array -- in this case, my array is of size 21 (21 elements, from 0 to 20) all assigned a value of 0 initially. It has 21 elements because I'm not going to use words that have more than 20 characters. I realize this is weird given no words have zero characters.
2. Begin counting characters in input.
3. If I encounter a space, tab, or newline character (i.e., this means the first word ended), stop.
4. Depending on how many characters the word had, increment that particular position in the array (i.e., if the word had two characters add 1 to the element at position 2 in the array).
5. Increment the wordCounter variable -- this variable as it's name indicates keeps track of the number of words that have been "read" in the input.
6. Continue doing this to each word until EOF is reached.

Here's my pseudocode for printing the histogram (horizontally).

1. For the first position, print the value stored in the first position of the array (i.e.,  0) using tick marks |
2. Do this for every element in the array.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZEOFWORDSOFLENGTH 21

int main() {
    int wordsOfLength[SIZEOFWORDSOFLENGTH];
    int c, i, j;
    int lengthCounter = 0;

    /*Initializing all array elements to 0.*/
    for (i = 0; i < SIZEOFWORDSOFLENGTH; i++)
        wordsOfLength[i] = 0;

    /*Going through the input and counting.*/
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++lengthCounter;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
            ++wordsOfLength[lengthCounter - 1];
            lengthCounter = 0;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZZEOFWORDSOFLENGTH; i++) {
        printf("Words of Length %d: ", i);
        /*The third argument of the following for loop was previously j = j*/
        for (j = 0; j < SIZEOFWORDSOFLENGTH; j++) {
            while (j < wordsOfLength[i]) {
                printf("|");
                /*Was previously j++ instead of break*/
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I debugged it by hand but I can't seem to find the problem. Maybe something really simple is going over my head. Also, I know this question has been asked before but I'm not trying to find a solution for the actual problem, I think my pseudocode is right if not somewhat right, I just want to know what's wrong with my code and maybe learn something. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that you should use the macro SIZEOFWORDSOFLENGTH in the declaration of `wordsOfLength`.  You should review what happens if the first character in your file is a blank or tab or newline.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks Jonathan, I forgot to mention that I was assuming I had no leading space, tabs, or newlines. I also included the macro SIZEOFWORDSOFLENGTH in the declaration of wordsOfLength.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in [Ji-Young Park](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3835311/ji-young-park)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24836709/15168), the reading loop has problems because it uses negative indexes into the array `wordsOfLength`.  I would keep life simple and have `wordsOfLength[i]` store the number of words of length `i`, though it effectively wastes `wordsOfLength[0]`.  I would use the macros from `<ctype.h>` to spot word boundaries, and I'd keep a record of whether I was in a word or not.  You get credit for using `int c`.

```
int inword = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (!isspace(c))
        lengthCounter++;
    else if (inword)
    {
        wordsOfLength[lengthCounter]++;
        lengthCounter = 0;
        inword = 0;
    }
}
if (inword)
    wordsOfLength[lengthCounter]++;
```

This code is not bamboozled by leading white space in the file.  If you think there's any risk of reading 'antidisestablishmentarianism' (28) or 'floccinaucinihilipilification' (29) or other grotesquely long words, you should check on `lengthCounter` before blindly using it as an index, either dropping overlong words from the count or mapping them all to '20+ characters' class.

Your final triple loop is quite problematic too — it is currently:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZZEOFWORDSOFLENGTH; i++) {
    printf("Words of Length %d: ", i);
    /*The third argument of the following for loop was previously j = j*/
    for (j = 0; j < SIZEOFWORDSOFLENGTH; j++) {
        while (j < wordsOfLength[i]) {
            printf("|");
            /*Was previously j++ instead of break*/
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Under my scheme, I'd start with `i = 1`, but that isn't a major issue.  I'd ensure that the first `printf()` printed for 2 digits to align the output for the counts of words of lengths 10-20.

The inner `for` loop should be constrained by `wordsOfLength[i]` rather than `SIZEOFWORDSOFLENGTH`, and the `while` loop is redundant (not least because you break it on the first iteration each time).  You just need simple nested `for` loops:

```
for (i = 1; i < SIZZEOFWORDSOFLENGTH; i++)
{
    printf("Words of Length %2d: ", i);
    for (j = 0; j < wordsOfLength[i]; j++)
        printf("|");
    printf("\n");
}
```

The only issue now is if the maximum value in `wordsOfLength` is too long for comfort (for example, you've read the entire works of Shakespeare, so some of the words appear thousands of times).

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to substract '1' from lengthCounter in

```
++wordsOfLength[lengthCounter - '1'];
```

It should be

```
++wordsOfLength[lengthCounter];
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Let's say I write something like "Hi my name is Rene" as input. Doesn't lengthCounter have a value of 3 by the third iteration of the while loop? And since the first word "Hi" is of length two, wouldn't I need to subtract by one, making it [lengthCoutner - '1']. I'd be incrementing the second position of the array by doing ++wordsOfLength[lengthCounter - '1']; no?

Comment: @ReneAlejandroSantiago: The use of `lengthCounter - '1'` (with single quotes around the `1`) means you are probably subtracting 49 from the length.  You might have a better argument if you wrote `lengthCounter - 1` (without the single quotes around the `1`).

Comment: Ah, right, in case, you need to substract 1, instead of '1'. '1' is a character, not a number, when you use '1' in arithmetic expression, it's converted into an integer value 49.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler

This particular program relies on the properties of the character representation of the digits. For example, the test
if (c >= ’0’ && c <= ’9’)
determines whether the character in c is a digit. If it is, the numeric value of that digit is
c - ’0’
This works only if ’0’,
’1’, ..., ’9’ have
consecutive increasing values. Fortunately, this is true for all character sets.

I really don't know what that means, I though I could use '1' instead of 1. You guys are telling me that '1' is the ASCII equivalent of 49 right?

Comment: @ReneAlejandroSantiago In C, 1 and '1' means different. You can see the difference if you run the following code
    print("%d\n", (int)1);
    print("%d\n", (int)'1');
'1'  is an character representation of a number 1, and doesn't actually mean number 1. You can see the value of ASCII characters on http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: @ReneAlejandroSantiago: I don't see any code that tests against digits.  All character sets support, and the C standard requires, that the code points of the digits are contiguous so that `'9' - '0'` is always `9` (§5.2.1 Character sets).  The standard does not require that the code point for `'0'` be 48 (it allows EBCDIC, for example, where that is not the value), but that is the most common value.  And what I'm telling you is that in ASCII, and Unicode, and the ISO 8859-x code sets, and many Windows code pages, the code for `'1'` is indeed 49.